# How to increase the size of Solr apis response Result

Tags: solr, solrj, solr4, alfresco-webscripts

I am using the Following apis to find out the failed indexed files and unindexed files

```
https://localhost:8443/solr4/alfresco/afts?q=DOC_TYPE:ErrorNode

https://localhost:8443/solr4/alfresco/afts?q=DOC_TYPE:UnindexedNode
```

Its giving only 10 results at a time can anyone tell me how to increase the response result. I want all the result at a time

Answer (score 0):

Increase the query result window by adding

```
rows=<size>
```

where size is the size of the result. Hence, try these commands:

```
https://localhost:8443/solr4/alfresco/afts?q=DOC_TYPE:ErrorNode&rows=<size>

https://localhost:8443/solr4/alfresco/afts?q=DOC_TYPE:UnindexedNode&rows=<size>
```

Comment: do u know the query through that  i can  find all duplicate index ??

Comment: is there any api to search duplicate indexs like above?